# Do special “set up to fail” projects exist?

Tags: professional-development

Does this occur often in companies?  Are there special projects like new technology projects (cross functional) that unwanted employees are put in disguised as a challenging growth project designed to either push out or set employees up to fail?  I’ve seen some of these in previous company where some employees on invites / emails where several months later are not there anymore and they are not the “popular” or intelligent employees.  If it’s such a great growth opportunity then why would they quit?  Does this exist?

And how can you spot these ‘opportunities’ and be able to back out of them at the onset before getting knees deep and realizing... the inevitable.

Comment: Don't attribute to malice that which can be attributed to incompetence.

Comment: Welcome to the site @SouthernBelle. Could you clarify what you are hoping to learn with this question? Bad companies, managers, or projects all exist. Promising projects go wrong. People make poor choices. But you don't seem to have an actionable goal in mind that can actually be answered.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Is there a real-world problem you are trying to solve? We can't answer hypothetical questions here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question boils down to: Are people assigned to projects for manipulative reasons in the workplace? And the answer is: yes, not everybody uses these tactics but some people do.

**1.**

I've seen managers assigning coworkers they didn't like or whose position they considered as too weak to object to projects famous for burning people out and being hell on earth. I've even gone through that myself and quit as a result. After I did, my former colleagues told me: "Well, you were on Project A, it's understandable you wanted out".

In this case, it's hard to say whether it was a malicious plan or incompetence.

**2.**

I've also witnessed managers assigning unliked colleagues to projects they didn't really want to take the sponsorship for. Their (unspoken) attitude was e.g.: "You are to take over the responsibility for Task A for our team. But I will never support you in public and if someone asks me, it was your idea to try to take over A, since I don't want to lose my political capital struggling for that".

Project sponsorship is normally incredibly important for project success.

In this constellation, the employee can only lose: if they manage to take over A, everyone will hate them. If they don't, they haven't completed the task they were assigned by manager.

The manager on the other hand can only win. If their employee manages to take over A, the unit gets more responsibility and becomes more important. If they don't, their manager is not losing anything as they distanced themselves from them.

These projects weren't doomed from the beginning. But lack of the managers' will made them so.

**3.**

The third example would be when my former "grand boss" searched for reasons to fire my boss for. They made them take on very ambitious - unrealistic - objectives and fail badly. Everyone would.

They also made them accept a 360 degree evaluation knowing the team was super conflicted and everybody who would agree to that would receive a super bad feedback.

And yes, then my then boss was fired using the arguments 360 feedback and his results.

Comment: I think you meant to say "who wouldn't agree to that...", not "who would agree to that..."

Answer (score 11):

The reverse is probably more common, i.e. you have a poorly thought out high profile project with unrealistic deadlines that has to be done as is because of factors external to your area.

So the project is doomed to fail.

Who do you put on this project?  People you like and want to work with, or people you dislike and don't want to work with?

Its less of a planned manipulation of the system and planned waste of resources as it is putting the deadwood on the sinking ship.

Answer (score -1):

> And how can you spot these ‘opportunities’ and be able to back out of them at the onset before getting knees deep and realizing

You can't, anything new is potentially going to fail either intentionally or not. If you want to avoid them, then stay with your role. If they want you to fail they don't need you to volunteer, you won't be given an option.

> Does this occur often in companies?

No it doesn't occur often, it's bad for business and there is usually some controls and accountability. But it does occur.

Answer (score -3):

I’ve seen it, but it’s rare. The problem with set up to fail projects is that they consume more resources and time than just letting the employees go in the first place. Maybe Europe with its difficult employment laws has more of this as people can’t be fired.

Comment: People most certainly _can_ be fired in Europe. I've seen people made redundant (their position was no longer needed, and/or they were considered untrainable for another position), which does require _some_ severance pay and the position cannot be refilled for a short time after, and seen people fired with cause (expenses fraud and the like), which is immediate and does not require severance and the company is allowed to hire a replacement. European law does protect you from at-will dumping, however.

Comment: Even in Europe, different countries have different employment laws. So an international company might try to move unwanted employees to projects located in another country in which its easier to fire people.